# Can a pyqtgraph.GraphicsObject be in two plots

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have two plots for left and right sensors. The plots have both their axes locked and will have certain labes and lines which should be rendered identically on both plots.

If I use addItem to add my items to 2 plots, it appears the second plot always gets the item.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

view = pg.GraphicsView()
l = pg.GraphicsLayout()
view.setCentralItem(l)
view.show()
view.resize(800,600)

p0 = l.addPlot(0, 0)
p1 = l.addPlot(1, 0)

p1.setXLink(p0)
p1.setYLink(p0)

line = pg.InfiniteLine()

p0.addItem(line)
p1.addItem(line)

app.exec_()
```

Is there anyway to have a single item on both plots? or a better way to skin this cat?

Comment: I just asked a very similar question then found yours. Did you ever find an answer @Techniquab?

Comment: From what I’ve learned since then, I don’t think a QGraphicsItem can belong to more than one scene (or Pyqtgraph plot) - after all, items have a function scene() which works like parent().  However, I think a scene can be viewed in multiple QGraphicsView widgets simultaneously each with its own scaling etc…though I never tried. I ended up creating duplicate items for the use case I had here.

Comment: I've also resorted to just duplicating the items. The multiple scene views sounds promising though, thanks!